# CSS body over riding H1 style

Tags: html, css

So I am having an issue with setting up my styles.css file and attaching it to my index.html file.

For some reason the body in the css file is overriding the h1 css.

Here's the code, and sorry if there's any glaring mistakes. I am brand new to this stuff.

```
h1 {
font-style: Georgia;
font-size: 48px;
color: red:
}
body {
    font-style: Georgia;
    font-size: 14px;

}
```

and my html index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> 

<head>
    <title>rdhamill's personal github page. </title>
</head>

<h1> Github.io page for Rdhamill </h1>  


<body>  
     This is where I plan on adding a list of projects, accomplishments, contact info and career goals. So stay tuned, and thanks for all the fish. 
</body> 

</html>
```

Edit: thanks for the help and sorry for the obvious issues!

Comment: Your h1 is outside the body which isn't allowed

Comment: Your link tag is also outside of the head. The <html> tag should only have two children: <head> and <body>. Everything else goes in one of those.

Comment: Also close your `color: red:` with `;` instead of `:`

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your `h1` tag is outside the body, put that inside.

And in addition to that put the `link` tag inside the `head` tag.

And in addition to that remove `:` from the end of the color attribute in `h1` style.

Answer (score 3):

All your elements need to be inside the `head` or `body` tags. See the snippet below to see where your elements belong. The text inside the `p` tag is just to clean it up a bit.

edit: as per [Dude Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9134576/dude-coder)'s [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50823874/8189007), fixed the CSS declaration. Make sure they always end in semi-colons, instead of colons.

Also changed `font-style` to `font-family`, which only needs to be set on the body (in this case, as all descendants will inherit it until it's changed elsewhere).

```css
h1 {
 font-size: 48px;
 color: red;
}

body {
 font-family: Georgia;
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>rdhamill's personal github page. </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> 
</head>
<body>  
 <h1> Github.io page for Rdhamill </h1> 
 <p>This is where I plan on adding a list of projects, accomplishments, contact info and career goals. So stay tuned, and thanks for all the fish.</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is too complex for an old browser to understand and render correctly. `<h1>` should be placed inside `<body>`. `<link>` should be placed inside `<head>`. Your CSS also has a typographical error. Either drop the final colon in `color: red` or type a semicolon; a colon won't work.

Back to the main subject:

The browser (a modern one) automatically places `<h1>` inside `<body>` and `<link>` inside `<head>`. And according to W3C, when you define the same style for an element and its child, the style defined for the child has priority over that defined for the parent element. Therefore, your `body` rule is **not** overriding `h1`. The problem is typographical: you typed a `:` instead of a `;`

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size:   48px;
  color:       red;
}

body {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size:   14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>rdhamill's personal github page. </title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Github.io page for Rdhamill </h1>
  This is where I plan on adding a list of projects, accomplishments, contact info and career goals. So stay tuned, and thanks for all the fish.
</body>

</html>
```

One a side note: I replaced `font-style` with `font-family`. To specify the font, use `font-family`. `font-style` is used for enhancements (italic, underline, etc...).